# How to stop PHP redirect loop

Tags: php, loops, redirect

I have a problem with PHP redirect.

This is in my profile page(check which user is login, customer or organization):

```
session_start();
// Check whether the user is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['isLogin']) && $_SESSION['isLogin'] == true && isset($_SESSION['loginSide']) && isset($_SESSION['userID']) && $_SESSION['userID'] != "") {
    if($_SESSION['loginSide'] == "customer") {
        header('Location: profile.php');
    } else if($_SESSION['loginSide'] == "organizations") {
        header('Location: organization.php');
    }

} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

How can I stop this loop? Thanks.

Comment: You need to show the code in profile.php, organization.php and index.php

Comment: You say "This is in my profile page" but one of your headers is `profile.php` so it's a bit unclear what this page is and how it fits into this scenario. If this is `profile.php` then you have the potential to loop on that one... Also that first `if` condition is very long and you could rewrite that better/clearer.

Comment: You would benefit from more human-readable super simple functions like `is_loggedin()` where that function is just: `return (!empty($_SESSION['isLogin']));` or `userId_set()` which would do pretty much the same: `return (!empty($_SESSION['userID']));` so your `if` condition would be like `if(is_loggedin() && userID_set()) { //do stuff }`

Comment: Lastly, you should be putting `exit;` after your headers to stop further execution of script.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post the answer (or ask whoever provided the correct one to) and mark it the correct solution, please don't change the title of the question.